# Help me please with writing a Plug-in in C# which exports it's on let say Config GUI

Tags: c#, plugins

I am kind of new to C# .Net and I am enjoying the learning process!
Right now I am working on a project (just to learn) in which plug-ins are the main key.

I did the following till now which seems to work fine:

Interface:

```
namespace My.test
{
    public interface IMyPlugin
    {
        bool Execute(string Id, Object param);
        List<string> GetPluginIdList();
    }
}
```

a test plug-in implementing IMyPlugin Interface:

```
using System;
..
..
using My.test;

namespace demoplg
{
    public class SamplePlugIn: IMyPlugin
    {

        public bool Execute(string Id, object param)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Id, "SamplePlugIn");
            return false;
        }

        public List<string> GetPluginIdList()
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            result.Add("test1");
            result.Add("test2");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the main application (Host) I am using Reflections to load the Dll (assembly) and create an Instance of the plug-in.

```
try
            {
                Type[] types = PlugIn.GetTypes();
                Type MyPlugInType = null;
                foreach (Type libtype in types)
                {
                    //check if it implements the IMyPlugin.
                    Type[] interfacelist = libtype.GetInterfaces();
                    foreach (Type lookupInf in interfacelist)
                    {
                        if (lookupInf.Name.Equals("IMyPlugin"))
                        {
                            MyPlugInType = libtype;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (MyPlugInType == null) continue;

                    IMyPlugin xplg = null;
                    ConstructorInfo ci = MyPlugInType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
                    xplg = ci.Invoke(null) as IMyPlugin;
                    return xplg;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
```

well, now what I want to have is, that a plug-in can have it's on configuration GUI, which I would like to add that in my Host (Main application) by calling something for example:
xplg.RegisterPluginGUI();

Let say something in the form of a tree-view on the left side showing the name/description of the plug-in, and on the right side kind of a container where I can drop the UI of the plug-in on it.

can some one please give some advice how to achieve this?

Well, I've done something similar in Delphi which is not a very clean work ;-)
Using WIN API to process the messages of a from inside a dll cached in the main form!!!

Thanks in advance!
AK

Comment: Just as an aside, look into the Mono.Addins framework. They have an easy system for registering plugins, it will save you searching around using reflection for implementations of your interfaces. Trust me, what you are doing now will get painful if you start creating more plugin interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to your interface IMyPlugin a method or a property which returns the configuration control:

```
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    UserControl GetConfigurationControl();
}

public class SamplePlugIn: IMyPlugin
{
    public UserControl GetConfigurationControl()
    {
        return new MyConfigurationControl();
    }
}

public class MyConfigurationControl : UserControl
{
}
```

After that, you can use the user control in a form in your application.

If you prefer to use a form, another option is:

```
public interface IMyPlugin
{
    void ConfigurePlugin();
}

public class SamplePlugIn: IMyPlugin
{
    public void ConfigurePlugin()
    {
        using(YourPluginConfigurationForm dlg = new YourPluginConfigurationForm())
        {
             dlg.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The Form idia is simple and IMHO the easiest to Implement.
The UserControl idia is interesting and I've to give a try to see if I can still use for example TAB key to jump from one control to the other between the Host control and the Plug-in Controls.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little offtopic but I would recommend you to learn following libraries for plugins development instead of creating your own:

[Managed Extensibility Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/MEF)

[System.AddIn Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163476.aspx)

If your goal is just learning then your code might be OK, but in real-world scenarios you should use proven solutions like those mentioned above.

Also I want to mention that MEF is open-source project and you can possibly find answers on many questions regarding plugins architecture.

Comment: Thank you for the links! I'll check them for sure!

Comment: +1 for mention of MEF. Using something pre-built is a good idea if there's a good match as it eases maintenance.